# Create a read-only file

Tags: java, file, readonly

I was wondering wether it is possible to create or simulate a file with a content set at creation and the assurance that nobody can ever change the file.
If possible, can I do it in java?

Comment: Well, you could write it to a DVD-R where it can be replaced, but the original always remains written.

Comment: Are you looking for [File.setReadOnly()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadOnly())

Comment: A DVD-ROM would be sort of a solution but unfortunately it would not be very scaleable and probably people are not very willing to insert a DVD-ROM to run a program :p

Comment: What is the use-case for doing such a thing?

Comment: If somebody runs my program and authenticates I want to be sure that network services from a server arrive at the computer the user registered my program on or not at all. (for example if somebody copies the program and authentication and installs it on another computer I want to be able to identify requests from the new computer as invalid) - I hope I'm not being confusing?

Comment: I could thus check an immutable file's content and it's creation date

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-authentication-and-authorization-service-jaas-reference-guide.html#GUID-2A935F5E-0803-411D-B6BC-F8C64D01A25C)

Answer (score 7):

Setting a file to read only is not going to make it so no one can ever change it.  It takes about 3 seconds to unset the read only flag.  The file can then be opened in a hex editor or other program that can handle the file type and changes can be made.

Answer (score 3):

yes we can make read only file in java using setReadOnly() method.

After using this method, you will not be able to write or edit into the file.

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileReadOnly {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("c:/file.txt");
    file.setReadOnly();
    System.out.println("File is in read only mode");
    }
}
```

or in this way also.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileAttributesDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create a new file, by default canWrite=true, readonly=false
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
      file.delete();
    }
    file.createNewFile();
    System.out.println("Before. canWrite?" + file.canWrite());

    // set to read-only, atau canWrite = false */
    file.setWritable(false);
    System.out.println("After. canWrite?" + file.canWrite());
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it enough to o setWritable(true) to be able to write again?

Comment: One could probably change the read-only property of the file later no? And than modify and set the property back, so I wouldn't even know it changed

Answer (score 2):

If you simply just need to create a Read-Only file, then won't the code below be sufficient? Unless I am missing something from your question:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileAttributesDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create a new file, by default canWrite=true, readonly=false
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
      file.delete();
    }
    file.createNewFile();
    System.out.println("Before. canWrite?" + file.canWrite());

    // set to read-only, atau canWrite = false */
    file.setWritable(false);
    System.out.println("After. canWrite?" + file.canWrite());
  }
}
```

Comment: I could just run another program and set writable to true again, no?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- file.setReadOnly()
- Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib " + "" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "" + " +R"); //(works on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

To make it so setWritable(true) does not enable writing again you could extend File and override the setWritable() methods.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Override;

public class FileAttributeDemo2 {
    private static class ReadOnlyFile extends File {
        public ReadOnlyFile(String pathname) {
            super(pathname);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean setWritable(boolean writeable) {
            return setWritable(writeable, true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean setWritable(boolean writeable, boolean ownerOnly) {
            if (!writeable) {
                return super.setWritable(false, ownerOnly);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new ReadOnlyFile("test.txt");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        file.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("Before. canWrite? " + file.canWrite());

        file.setWritable(false);
        System.out.println("Set writable false. canWrite? " + file.canWrite());

        file.setWritable(true);
        System.out.println("Set writable true. canWrite? " + file.canWrite());

    }
}
```

which produces the output:

```
Before. canWrite? true 
Set Writable False. canWrite? false 
Set Writable True. canWrite? false
```

Comment: But one could just directly change the read-only property using for example another java process

Comment: yes, they could run another process, or they could simply right-click, select Properties and untick the little box and then proceed to have their way with your file.

Answer (score 0):

Read-only way can be useful altough it is not impossible to change or crack.So if you can not create an unreachable file then you can convert its contents to not understandable thanks to some kind of Encryption algorithms.For example AES may be so usefull.

Answer (score 0):

In this case simply you have to create a file using File class after that by reference you have to call setReadOnly() method.

```
    File f=new File("abc.txt");
    f.setReadOnly();
```