# Can I save a text file without giving users ability to modify it?

Tags: java, file, save

I'm working on a game and I am at that part that I want to save the game progress into a text file (or maybe a properties file would be good too), but I'd like to save that file to a place that is not reachable for the players. I was thinking about saving it to a source folder inside the program, but I am not able to save or load a text file from there, only images. Could anybody suggest something how/where to save the game stats that players can not just go into the settings file and modify their score or level or something like that?

With the properties file my only problem is the saving, where I need an output stream or a writer to save it, what I', not able to get

Comment: I would think that using an in-memory database such as H2 would be better and easier.  Its super easy to setup.  If you've already written code to create the file then just save the file in an appropriate field in the DB e.g. BLOB or VARCHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your player's pc has a regular hard drive with regular standards then:

If the game is offline(and maybe later synced with a server) then the answer is NO; if your app can access the file so does the user; even if you encrypt the data written to the save file people can just reverse engineer your app and get the keys and algorithms and modify the file; to put it simply you can only complicate it, their access to save files is inevitable.

If your game is only possible to be played online then you can do sanity check for every action of the players and save the progress in an inaccessible by players manner;

Answer (score 1):

About the read only, been asked before:
[create a read-only file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477257/create-a-read-only-file)

For the second one, keep in mind that as you know the path to the file and the name of it, the user don't. Saving the file using "scary" name, in un-trivial path will protect the file from any changes for a while

Comment: Yes, the scary name would protect them for a while but there are lot of users that download a game just to find some ways to cheat and upload it. Any idea how to make the game unreadable or unaccessible at all?

Comment: Not making a game is one way.
Cheating will always be, if it that bothers you, you can add anti-cheat system like for example, GTA VC anti-piracy system